# Finding the optimal bijective map between two sets of natural numbers

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, optimization

I have two sets $A$ and $B$, each containing $N$ high-dimensional vectors.
I have an $N\times N$ matrix, $M$, where $M_{i,j}=\text{Dist}||A_i,B_j||$.

I am trying to find a bijective map $A\rightarrow B$ that minimises the average distance between paired elements.

The surjective case is obviously trivial; just map $A_i$ to $B_j$ where $j=\text{argmax}(M_{i,j})$. However I want a 1-to-1 mapping.

$N$ is not very large (~5), but I have many such pairs and need to find an algorithm in order to automate the process.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called an *Assignment problem*. You can formulate you problem as the following integer program:

$$
 min \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N} x_{ij} M_{ij} \\ 
s.t. \sum_{i=1}^{N}x_{ij} = 1 \;\forall j \in N \\
\sum_{j=1}^{N}x_{ij} = 1 \; \forall i \in N \\
0 \leq x_{ij} \leq 1 \;\forall i\in N,j \in N \\
x_{ij} \in \mathbb{Z} \;\forall i\in N,j \in N
$$

This problem can be solved by solving the linear relaxation of the above IP (drop the integer constraint) with e.g. the *Simplex Method*.

Comment: Thank you this was the information I needed. Knowing the correct terminology for my problem allowed me to find a handy one-line implementation of the simplex method, and has solved my problem.